# How to resolve "io.cucumber.core.backend.ObjectFactory" compiler error in Cucumber Maven project?

Tags: maven, cucumber, testng

I have created a Maven project with the Cucumber BDD framework in Java. I have tried everything but Test Runner class always shows below compiler error.

Error is: The type io.cucumber.core.backend.ObjectFactory cannot be resolved. It's indirectly referenced from required .class files.

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzxL6.png)

[Test Runner class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEqmc.png)

I am stuck here for a long time and completely devasted now.

Thanks in Advance.

**POM.xml**

```
*<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
  <artifactId>cucumber-archetype</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>hellocucumber_1</name>
  <description>hellocucumber_1</description>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
      <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
      <version>1.6</version>
      <scope>system</scope>
      <systemPath>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.6\lib\tools.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
        <version>6.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>6.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.13</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.6</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
        <version>15.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.19</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.cobertura</groupId>
        <artifactId>cobertura</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>29.0-jre</version>
    </dependency>   
  </dependencies>
</project>*
```

Comment: Please don't ever use screenshots for code. They are hard to read.

Comment: And you should use a tool to manage your dependencies. Try the tutorial. https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/10-minute-tutorial/

Comment: That would be helpful for us. If you share pom.xml content here.

Comment: Hi M.P.Korstanje and @UnknownBeast, I tried this one but unable to find a solution. So, as per above comment sharing the POM xml. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Adding cucumber-core dependency to pom.xml helped me resolve the same issue.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
    <version>6.10.4</version>
</dependency>
```